# Adding up part-time jobs in R

Tags: r

I have the following snapshot of monthly dataset (I represent here only the first two months, but I have this data for approximately 300,000 individuals for every month in 2014).

```
df<-data.frame( c(20140101, 20140116, 20140201, 20140215, 20150101, 20150201, 20150101, 20150201, 20150201), 
                c(20140115, 20140131, 20140214, 20140228, 20150131, 20150228, 20150131, 20150228, 20150228),
                c(15, 16, 14, 14, 31, 28, 31, 28, 28),
                c(0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2),
                c("q1", "q1", "q1", "q2","q2","q2", "q3", "q3", "q3"))
colnames(df)<-c("Begindate", "Enddate", "Duration", "part-time", "id")
```

Which yields the following output

```
ID   Begindate     Enddate      Duration part-time 
q1   2014-01-01   2014-01-15      15       0.8
q1   2014-01-16   2014-01-31      16       0.4
q1   2014-02-01   2014-02-14      14       0.8
q1   2014-02-15   2014-02-28      14       0.4
q2   2015-01-01   2015-01-31      31       0.8
q2   2015-02-01   2015-02-28      28       0.8
q3   2015-01-01   2015-01-31      31       0.8
q3   2015-02-01   2015-02-28      28       0.8
q3   2015-02-01   2015-02-28      28       0.2
```

The story that corresponds with the above dataset is more or less as follows. The individual q1 works two jobs every month. At one of the jobs he works 0.8 and at the other one he works 0.4. Individual q2 has only one job and works there for 0.8 each month. Lastly, individual q3 worked one job in january for equal to 0.8 of a full-time job. However , as of february he started to take on another job next to the job he already had.

Now I would like to rewrite this data as follows

```
ID   Begindate     Enddate      part-time 
q1   2014-01-01   2014-01-31       0.6
q1   2014-02-01   2014-02-28       0.6
q2   2015-01-01   2015-01-31       0.8
q2   2015-02-01   2015-02-28       0.8
q3   2015-01-01   2015-01-31       0.8
q3   2015-02-01   2015-02-28       1.0
```

In other words, I would like to rewrite the data such that I have a part-time number for each individual at the monthly level. In other words, q2 does not change wheras the four lines of q1 should be coerced into 1 line for each month (I rounded the part time factors as you may have noticed). Moreover, for q3 the first month should not change, but the second month should be coerced into one line. Note that I dropped the duration variable. This is just to avoid confusion as I am interested in the part-time number.

Does anyone here has any idea on how to do this. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This might not work out for other purposes, but you can create an artificial `month` column, then aggregate using that. I'm using coerce = `mean`, but it could be other function. It would be something like `df %>% mutate(month = month(Begindate)) %>% group_by(month) %>% summarise(part_time = mean(part_time))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Matias, you can create month and year columns to combine rows and summarize by month/year. However, you will need to `group_by` `ID` as well. In addition, you might want to use `Duration` for each row as well as total number of days in the month to calculate a weighted sum.

**Edit (3/19/20)**: Edited with change in example data and column names in question. Also included `lubridate` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Begindate = as.Date(as.character(Begindate), format = "%Y%m%d"),
         Enddate = as.Date(as.character(Enddate), format = "%Y%m%d")) %>%
  group_by(id, month = month(Begindate), year = year(Begindate)) %>%
  summarise(Begindate = first(Begindate),
            Enddate = last(Enddate),
            monthdays = as.numeric(difftime(Enddate, Begindate, units = "days")) + 1,
            part.time = round(sum(`part-time` * (Duration / monthdays)), 1))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
# Groups:   id, month [6]
  id    month  year Begindate  Enddate    monthdays part.time
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>
1 q1        1  2014 2014-01-01 2014-01-31        31       0.6
2 q1        2  2014 2014-02-01 2014-02-14        14       0.8
3 q2        1  2015 2015-01-01 2015-01-31        31       0.8
4 q2        2  2014 2014-02-15 2014-02-28        14       0.4
5 q2        2  2015 2015-02-01 2015-02-28        28       0.8
6 q3        1  2015 2015-01-01 2015-01-31        31       0.8
7 q3        2  2015 2015-02-01 2015-02-28        28       1
```

Comment: Hi ben, I tried you code today and for some reason it goes wrong with the summarise command. More precisely, he just does not group_by id and gives just the begindate and the enddate of the entire sample and then he adds up all the parttime factors. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: no it did not work before. I added the data and it does not work on my small sample as well. Hope you have any idead what the problem could be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Albert I updated the answer. The data looks different (e.g., numeric dates) so changed the `as.Date` info. Column names changed (such as `part-time` - recommend using underscore `_` instead of hyphen in names). Also forgot you should use `lubridate` package for `month`. Otherwise seems to work. Check the output to see if this is what you would expect for your example data. Hope this helps.